# Issues with Node.js REPL

Tags: node.js

I am having problems with node.js REPL. I put in the following line into the node REPL:

> var p = {fname: "john", lname= "Doe"}

What I get back is an ellipsis (...) as if REPL is waiting for a continuation. I also try to put a ; at the end, or taking the var keyword out, but get the same result.

Why does it think that it is not the end of a statement? What am I missing?

env: Node version 0.6.2, running on windows.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong, it should be:

```
var p = {fname: "john", lname: "Doe"}
```

(note the `:` instead of `=`)

Comment: Dang, I just spent two hours on the #$#@# thing. Thanks!!